# Computing the wedge product

Tags: python, geometry, sympy

A differential geometry questions, how exactly do I use the WedgeProduct in sympy? Here's an example of a problem I want to solve:

[image]

I've tried:

```py
In [28]: from sympy.diffgeom import WedgeProduct

In [29]: from sympy.diffgeom.rn import R3_r

In [30]: e_x, e_y, e_z = R3_r.base_vectors()

In [49]: u = e_x + 2 * e_y

In [50]: v = e_x + e_y - e_z

In [51]: WedgeProduct(u, v)
Out[51]: WedgeProduct(e_x + 2*e_y, e_x + e_y - e_z)
```

but that's not what I want. The docs are sparse and a bit confusing, how do I get sympy to expand out the WedgeProduct like in the example?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
e_x, e_y, e_z = R3_r.base_vectors()
dx, dy, dz = R3_r.base_oneforms()
u = e_x + 2 * e_y
v = e_x + e_y - e_z
assert WedgeProduct(dx, dy)(u, v) == -1
assert WedgeProduct(dx, dz)(u, v) == -1
assert WedgeProduct(dy, dz)(u, v) == -2
```

Which agrees with the computation-by-hand above.